# ProfileCommon.Save() restarts IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, asp.net-membership, membership-provider

In my ManageAccounts.aspx page I use

```
<asp:CreateUserWizard runat="server" LoginCreatedUser="False" ID="createWizard" OnCreatedUser="CreatedUser">
```

in it's code behind ManageAccounts.aspx.cs I have my callback

```
    protected void CreatedUser(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // set up initial views for account
        ProfileCommon thisProfile = Profile.GetProfile(createWizard.UserName);
        thisProfile.SetPropertyValue("SomeProperty", "somevalue");

        try{
            thisProfile.Save();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
        // this is never hit
        }
    }
```

When `CreatedUser` is called after account is created everything works well until thisProfile.Save() is hit. Then application stops immediately. When debugging in Visual Studio after this line is executed application is stopped after error with just external call stack. OnError handler in Global.asax is not hit either so only exception message I'm getting is from Windows Event Log.

```
Log Name:      Application
Source:        ASP.NET 4.0.30319.0
Date:          3/7/2018 2:07:21 PM
Event ID:      1325
Task Category: None
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      C-Licensing-01
Description:
An unhandled exception occurred and the process was terminated.

Application ID: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT

Process ID: 4468

Exception: System.Runtime.FatalException

Message: An asynchronous operation cannot be started at this time. Asynchronous operations may only be started within an asynchronous handler or module or during certain events in the Page lifecycle. If this exception occurred while executing a Page, ensure that the Page is marked <%@ Page Async="true" %>. This exception may also indicate an attempt to call an "async void" method, which is generally unsupported within ASP.NET request processing. Instead, the asynchronous method should return a Task, and the caller should await it.

StackTrace:    at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage4(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage3(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage2(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage1(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.DispatchAndReleasePump(RequestContext request, Boolean cleanThread, OperationContext currentOperationContext)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.HandleRequest(RequestContext request, OperationContext currentOperationContext)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.AsyncMessagePump(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.OnAsyncReceiveComplete(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Runtime.Fx.AsyncThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.Complete(Boolean completedSynchronously)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportDuplexSessionChannel.TryReceiveAsyncResult.OnReceive(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Runtime.Fx.AsyncThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.Complete(Boolean completedSynchronously)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SynchronizedMessageSource.ReceiveAsyncResult.OnReceiveComplete(Object state)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SessionConnectionReader.OnAsyncReadComplete(Object state)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.StreamConnection.OnRead(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Runtime.Fx.AsyncThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.Complete(IntPtr userToken)
   at System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.ProtectedInvokeCallback(Object result, IntPtr userToken)
   at System.Net.Security._SslStream.ProcessFrameBody(Int32 readBytes, Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security._SslStream.ReadFrameCallback(AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.AsyncProtocolRequest.CompleteRequest(Int32 result)
   at System.Net.FixedSizeReader.CheckCompletionBeforeNextRead(Int32 bytes)
   at System.Net.FixedSizeReader.ReadCallback(IAsyncResult transportResult)
   at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.Complete(Boolean completedSynchronously)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionStream.IOAsyncResult.OnAsyncIOComplete(Object state)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.FinishRead()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.OnReceiveAsync(Object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs eventArgs)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.OnReceiveAsyncCompleted(Object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
   at System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs.OnCompleted(SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
   at System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs.FinishOperationSuccess(SocketError socketError, Int32 bytesTransferred, SocketFlags flags)
   at System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs.CompletionPortCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
   at System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP)

InnerException: System.InvalidOperationException

Message: An asynchronous operation cannot be started at this time. Asynchronous operations may only be started within an asynchronous handler or module or during certain events in the Page lifecycle. If this exception occurred while executing a Page, ensure that the Page is marked <%@ Page Async="true" %>. This exception may also indicate an attempt to call an "async void" method, which is generally unsupported within ASP.NET request processing. Instead, the asynchronous method should return a Task, and the caller should await it.

StackTrace:    at System.Web.AspNetSynchronizationContext.OperationStarted()
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ThreadBehavior.BindCore(MessageRpc& rpc, Boolean startOperation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage4(MessageRpc& rpc)
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="ASP.NET 4.0.30319.0" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="49152">1325</EventID>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2018-03-07T20:07:21.000000000Z" />
    <EventRecordID>6615</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>C-Licensing-01</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>An unhandled exception occurred and the process was terminated.
```

Focusing especially on message:

> An asynchronous operation cannot be started at this time. Asynchronous
>   operations may only be started within an asynchronous handler or
>   module or during certain events in the Page lifecycle. If this
>   exception occurred while executing a Page, ensure that the Page is
>   marked <%@ Page Async="true" %>. This exception may also indicate an
>   attempt to call an "async void" method, which is generally unsupported
>   within ASP.NET request processing. Instead, the asynchronous method
>   should return a Task, and the caller should await it.

As I'm going one-by-one through all possibilities I can think about putting `<%@ Page Async="true" %>` doesn't make any change in observed behavior.

Second part of message doesn't seem relevant for me as I'm not using any `async void` method in my application.

As a another weird thing is that this part of codebase was not modified for couple years but started to behave like this just few days ago so it was possibly caused by change in other part of application or by environmental change as another version of installed .NET framework.

As this seems to be possibly caused by something environmental and may be hard to discover I'd be grateful for any hint how to get more information about what's going on in w3wp.exe in time of crash.